# How to select any Video or Movie file from UIImagePickerController

Tags: iphone, uiimagepickercontroller

In my app, i need to select any video file and show the display the url for a video file in the application.

```
-(void)viewDidLoad{

    [super viewDidLoad];

    self.imgPicker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
    self.imgPicker.delegate = self;
    self.imgPicker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeSavedPhotosAlbum;
    self.imgPicker.mediaTypes = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:(NSString *)kUTTypeMovie, (NSString *)kUTTypeImage, nil];
    self.imgPicker.allowsEditing = NO;

    [self presentModalViewController:self.imgPicker animated:YES];
}

-(void)imagePickerControllerDidCancel:(UIImagePickerController *)picker{

    [picker dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}


-(void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker
      didFinishPickingImage : (UIImage *)image
                 editingInfo:(NSDictionary *)editingInfo{

}

- (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info{

    value = 1;

    IMAGE_COUNTER = IMAGE_COUNTER + 1;

    NSString* mediaType = [info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerMediaType]; 
    if ( [mediaType isEqualToString:@"public.movie" ])
    {
        NSLog(@"Picked a movie at URL %@",  [info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerMediaURL]);
        NSURL *url =  [info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerMediaURL];
        NSLog(@"> %@", [url absoluteString]); 
    } 

    else
    {
        UIImage *image = [info objectForKey:@"UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage"];

        NSData* imageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image, 1.0);

        NSString* incrementedImgStr = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"UserCustomPotraitPic%d.jpg", IMAGE_COUNTER];

        NSArray* paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
        NSString* documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];

        NSString* fullPathToFile2 = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:incrementedImgStr];
        [imageData writeToFile:fullPathToFile2 atomically:NO];
    }
}
```

I have used the above code to display image and video , every thing is coming fine, however when i select any video file, it didn't comes to UIImagePickerController Delegate Method, Video file directly plays, i don't want to play any video file, when i select any video file it should come in its delegate property

Answer (score 67, accepted):

Picking videos from the iPhone Library does not work on the iOS Simulator. Try it on a real iPhone.

Here is the code for picking video from the iOS Photo Library which I have used in my projects. Just add video method from selector to your desired button.

```
- (void)video {
    UIImagePickerController *imagePicker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
    imagePicker.delegate = self;
    imagePicker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary;
    imagePicker.mediaTypes = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:(NSString *)kUTTypeMovie,      nil];

    [self presentModalViewController:imagePicker animated:YES];
 }


- (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info {
    NSString *mediaType = [info objectForKey: UIImagePickerControllerMediaType];

    if (CFStringCompare ((__bridge CFStringRef) mediaType, kUTTypeMovie, 0) == kCFCompareEqualTo) {
        NSURL *videoUrl=(NSURL*)[info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerMediaURL];
        NSString *moviePath = [videoUrl path];

        if (UIVideoAtPathIsCompatibleWithSavedPhotosAlbum (moviePath)) {
            UISaveVideoAtPathToSavedPhotosAlbum (moviePath, nil, nil, nil);
        }
    }

    [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
    [picker release];
}
```

The string  `moviepath`  gives you the path of the selected video which can be used to perform any desired action with that video.

Don't forget to add the `MobileCoreServices.framework` Framework to your project! Then import it like this:

```
#import <MobileCoreServices/UTCoreTypes.h>
```

Comment: If you're using ARC, you can compare the media type a little more easily.     if ([mediaType isEqualToString:(__bridge NSString *)kUTTypeMovie]) {

Comment: You can also use syntactic sugar to create the array like this: `imagePicker.mediaTypes = @[(NSString *)kUTTypeMovie, (NSString*) kUTTypeImage];` (etc., add types as desired.)  Same functionality, just a bit less typing.  :)

Comment: Great answer :). I found that by setting picker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeSavedPhotosAlbum; brought up only a list of videos and found it was more useful for what I was after. Bear in mind the different source types will show different menus (for me using UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary brought up my photo albums but then displayed them empty of video)

Comment: You should file a radar about videos not working in the photo library in the simulator.  Unreported bugs don't get fixed ;)

Answer (score 7):

try this:-

```
   UIImagePickerController *imagePicker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
    imagePicker.delegate = self;
    imagePicker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeSavedPhotosAlbum;
    imagePicker.mediaTypes = [NSArray arrayWithObject:(NSString *)kUTTypeMovie];
    NSArray *sourceTypes = [UIImagePickerController availableMediaTypesForSourceType:imagePicker.sourceType];
    if (![sourceTypes containsObject:(NSString *)kUTTypeMovie ])
    {
        //NSLog(@"no video");
    }


    [self presentModalViewController:imagePicker animated:YES];
```

In delegate method:-

```
 - (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info
    {
            NSString *type = [info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerMediaType];
            //NSLog(@"type=%@",type);
            if ([type isEqualToString:(NSString *)kUTTypeVideo] || 
                [type isEqualToString:(NSString *)kUTTypeMovie])
            {// movie != video
                NSURL *urlvideo = [info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerMediaURL];
}
    }
```

Comment: Thanks Gypsa for quick reply however its not working, its still not coming under delegate method, when select any movie, I have 3 m4v movies in Simulator

Comment: check that in .h file you have not forgot to write:-<UIImagePickerControllerDelegate,UINavigationControllerDelegate>

Comment: I have implemented that however not any success still,

Comment: Does the `containsObject:` method work if I do, for example, `[((NSString *) kUTTypeVideo) copy]`?

Comment: use **import MobileCoreServices** for kUTTypeVideo

Answer (score 3):

Swift 3 update :

```
func galleryVideo() 
{        
    if UIImagePickerController.isSourceTypeAvailable(UIImagePickerControllerSourceType.savedPhotosAlbum) {

        let videoPicker = UIImagePickerController()
        videoPicker.delegate = self
        videoPicker.sourceType = .photoLibrary
        videoPicker.mediaTypes = [kUTTypeMovie as String]
        self.present(videoPicker, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
}
```

Import **import MobileCoreServices** and adding delegates **UIImagePickerControllerDelegate** and **UINavigationControllerDelegate** .

Answer (score 1):

@Dinesh Kaushik's code help to with the same problem I had.

I changed :

```
 //NSArray * availableMediaTypes = [UIImagePickerController availableMediaTypesForSourceType:UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary];
        //imagePickerController.mediaTypes = availableMediaTypes;

        imagePickerController.mediaTypes = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:(NSString *)kUTTypeMovie,      nil];
```

and only this way, I can see the video and select it. strange

Answer (score -5):

Do not use UIImagePicker, just use assetlibrary, implement custom video picker, access to selected video file directly, save the video file and compess the file if you want..

Comment: Why reinventing the wheel when Apple did it already? Today we all need to hurry and many of us are permanently on a tight schedule. So using the ready-implemented `UIImagePickerController` is definitely good practice! As a great plus the users are well familiar with this picker.