# Swift - Is it possible to select a video from the library on the iOS simulator?

Tags: ios, swift, video, ios-simulator, uiimagepickercontroller

All that shows up when I use the UIImagePickerController is a library of photos. I have an mp4 video saved to the simulator library, but it never shows up in the list when I access the simulator library programmatically with UIImagePickerController. Is there something I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Picking videos from the iPhone Library does not work on the iOS Simulator. Try it on a real iPhone.    Please check the answer for this question in SO: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10480170/how-to-select-any-video-or-movie-file-from-uiimagepickercontroller

Comment: Thank you for the response. I did check other questions. I just didn't want to assume those answers applied to every version of iOS and every situation. I'm very new to programming in Swift and for iOS. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

You just need to add a video to your simulator.

Drag and drop a video file on top of the simulator window. It will show in the photos app and whenever you want a video for upload.

Answer (score 0):

Based on Swift 2.2

Your code may look like this:

```
@IBAction func selectImageFromPhotoLibrary(sender: UIBarButtonItem) {

    let imagePickerController = UIImagePickerController()

    imagePickerController.sourceType = .PhotoLibrary
    imagePickerController.delegate = self

    imagePickerController.mediaTypes = ["public.image", "public.movie"]
    presentViewController(imagePickerController, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

Actually you can get the answers from the Apple Document:

[UIImagePickerController Class Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIImagePickerController_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007070-CH3-SW4)

The useful method is class func `availableMediaTypesForSourceType`.

You can try this:

```
let types = UIImagePickerController.availableMediaTypesForSourceType(.PhotoLibrary)
print(types)
```

Then you know videos types are named `public.movie` , not `kUTTypeMovie` anymore.