# Select video from PhotoLibrary in iOS using Swift

Tags: ios, swift, uiimagepickercontrollermediatype, mobilecoreservices

I am trying to select video from PhotoLibrary using following code

```
imageController.mediaTypes = [kUTTypeMovie: NSString]
```

After selecting video, when it is compressing, I am getting array out of boundary issue.

I searched online and found following line. I am unable to convert it into Swift version ([link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10480170/how-to-select-any-video-or-movie-file-from-uiimagepickercontroller))
`imageController.mediaTypes = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:(NSString *)kUTTypeMovie, nil]`

Please let us know the Swift version for above line. It is very useful if anyone can provide Swift version of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10480170/how-to-select-any-video-or-movie-file-from-uiimagepickercontroller).

**Question2**:

I want to show selected video in app and need to play when it is tapped. Can we do it without external plugins and using built in libraries?

Answer (score 43):

**Based on Swift 2.2**

Suppose you have a imagePickerController and when you want to select both images and videos:

```
let imagePickerController = UIImagePickerController()
var videoURL: NSURL?    

@IBAction func selectImageFromPhotoLibrary(sender: UIBarButtonItem) {
  imagePickerController.sourceType = .PhotoLibrary
  imagePickerController.delegate = self
  imagePickerController.mediaTypes = ["public.image", "public.movie"]

  presentViewController(imagePickerController, animated: true, completion: nil)    
}
```

Then after the video is selected, print out its NSURL.

```
func imagePickerController(picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [String : AnyObject]) {
  videoURL = info["UIImagePickerControllerReferenceURL"] as? NSURL
  print(videoURL)
  imagePickerController.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
}
```

For question 2:

Yes, you can do it through AVPlayer, you need import AVKit and AVFoundation, and you code may look like this:

```
if let videoURL = videoURL{
  let player = AVPlayer(URL: videoURL)

  let playerViewController = AVPlayerViewController()
  playerViewController.player = player

  presentViewController(playerViewController, animated: true) {
    playerViewController.player!.play()
  }
}
```

I made a [demo](https://github.com/KrisYu/stackoverflow) here you can refer, maybe not 100% what you want.

Comment: Is it possible to save the video in our app itself? So that instead of selecting it again and again they can directly view the video from a shortcut from the app itself.

Answer (score 18):

Swift 5+ solution:

```
func openVideoGallery() {
    picker = UIImagePickerController()
    picker.delegate = self
    picker.sourceType = .savedPhotosAlbum
    picker.mediaTypes = ["public.movie"]      
    picker.allowsEditing = false
    present(picker, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

Comment: Instead of using mediaType "public.movie", consider importing  UniformTypeIdentifiers and then use UTType.movie.identifier.

Comment: The `UTType` identifiers are only available in iOS 14 and later. It's not a big deal for most, but it does affect library maintainers that support older iOS versions.

Answer (score 17):

```
@IBOutlet weak var imgView: UIImageView!
var imagePickerController = UIImagePickerController()
var videoURL : NSURL?

@IBAction func btnSelectVideo_Action(_ sender: Any) {
    imagePickerController.sourceType = .savedPhotosAlbum
    imagePickerController.delegate = self
    imagePickerController.mediaTypes = [kUTTypeMovie as String]
    present(imagePickerController, animated: true, completion: nil)
}

func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [String : Any]) {
    videoURL = info[UIImagePickerControllerMediaURL]as? NSURL
    print(videoURL!)
    do {
        let asset = AVURLAsset(url: videoURL as! URL , options: nil)
        let imgGenerator = AVAssetImageGenerator(asset: asset)
        imgGenerator.appliesPreferredTrackTransform = true
        let cgImage = try imgGenerator.copyCGImage(at: CMTimeMake(0, 1), actualTime: nil)
        let thumbnail = UIImage(cgImage: cgImage)
        imgView.image = thumbnail
    } catch let error {
        print("*** Error generating thumbnail: \(error.localizedDescription)")
    }
    self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

**For question 2:**

```
let player = AVPlayer(url: videoURL)
let playerController = AVPlayerViewController()
playerController.player = player
self.present(playerController, animated: true) {
    player.play()

}
```

Comment: This really helped me out. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 12):

Swift 3

```
import MobileCoreServices

var imagePickerController = UIImagePickerController()
var videoURL: URL?

private func openImgPicker() {
    imagePickerController.sourceType = .savedPhotosAlbum
    imagePickerController.delegate = self
    imagePickerController.mediaTypes = ["public.movie"]
    present(imagePickerController, animated: true, completion: nil)
}

extension YourViewController: UIImagePickerControllerDelegate, UINavigationControllerDelegate {
    func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [String : Any]) {
        videoURL = info[UIImagePickerControllerMediaURL] as? URL
        print("videoURL:\(String(describing: videoURL))")
        self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
}
```

Comment: change info[UIImagePickerControllerMediaURL] to info[UIImagePickerController.InfoKey.mediaURL]

Answer (score 4):

**Select a Video from Gallery using Swift 4**

```
    // Put this code where you want to pick the video from gallery
    Let imagePickerController = UIImagePickerController ()
    imagePickerController.sourceType = .photoLibrary
    imagePickerController.delegate = self
    imagePickerController.mediaTypes = ["public.movie"]
    present(imagePickerController, animated: true, completion: nil)

    // UIImagePickerController Delegate Method
    func imagePickerController (_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [String: Any]) 
    {
         let videoURL = info[UIImagePickerControllerMediaURL] as? NSURL
         print(videoURL!)
         self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

```
func openCamera() {
  if UIImagePickerController.isSourceTypeAvailable(UIImagePickerControllerSourceType.Camera) {
    println("captureVideoPressed and camera available.")

    var imagePicker = UIImagePickerController()

    imagePicker.delegate = self
    imagePicker.sourceType = .Camera
    imagePicker.mediaTypes = [kUTTypeMovie!]
    imagePicker.allowsEditing = false

    imagePicker.showsCameraControls = true

    self.presentViewController(imagePicker, animated: true, completion: nil)   
  } else {
    println("Camera not available.")
  }  
}

func imagePickerController(  didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info:NSDictionary!) {
  videoUrl = info[UIImagePickerControllerMediaURL] as! NSURL!
  let pathString = videoUrl.relativePath
  self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
}
```

Comment: I already tried all these. Application is closing automatically after compressing video. Unable to find the issue.

Answer (score 3):

**Swift 4.0**

**Your class adopts the UIImagePickerControllerDelegate protocol**

```
class classname: UIViewController, UIImagePickerControllerDelegate, UINavigationControllerDelegate
```

**After that you need to create**

```
let imagePickerController = UIImagePickerController()
```

**Add this in your button's action:-**

```
imagePickerController.sourceType = .photoLibrary

imagePickerController.delegate = self

imagePickerController.mediaTypes = ["public.image", "public.movie"]

present(imagePickerController, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

**Delegate method**

```
func imagePickerController(picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [String : AnyObject]) {

 let videoURL = info["UIImagePickerControllerReferenceURL"] as? NSURL
 print(videoURL!)
 imagePickerController.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

try this pod that i've made :

```
https://github.com/jhonyourangel/ImagePickerWhatsApp
```

I was searching for a similar Image and Video Picker for a project and i wasn't able to find one that was able to :
1. Take picture
2. Get a Picture from the library
3. Register a Video
4. Get a video from the library

While i was looking i hopen whatsup of facebook or mabe google have a pod for this kind of needs, i realy liked the whatsapp picker, so i created this one similer to the one in whatsapp.

#### Prerequisites

In order to use ImageVideoPicker you need cocoapods and an xCode project already created

#### Installing

to install cocoapods is should be enough just to run `sudo gem install cocoapods` in the terminal
if this doen't work go to [cocoapods](https://cocoapods.org/)

Then navigate the terminal to your project folder, where the file extension `.xcodeproj` is located and run `pod init`
this will create a file called `Podfile`
Open the file in a editor ( sublimeText, xCode, atom, vim ... etc ) and add the line bellow after `use_frameworks!`

```
pod 'ImagePickerWhatsApp'
```

or 
    pod 'ImagePickerWhatsApp', :path => '/Users/aiu/Documents/cocoapods/ImagePickerWhatsApp'

then just run `pod install` in the terminal and wait to finish instaling the lib

#### How to use it

add `import ImagePickerWhatsApp` to your viewcontroller class

then you can call the picker by calling :
    let mp = ImageVideoPicker.makeVCFromStoryboard()
    self.present(mp, animated: true, completion: nil)

#### Delegate

to implement the delegate add `mp.delegate = self` and the extent the class of you view controller
aso you need to import the iOS Photos framework `import Photos`

```
extension ViewController: ImageVideoPickerDelegate {
    func onCancel() {
        print("no picture selected")
    }

    func onDoneSelection(assets: [PHAsset]) {
       print("selected \(assets.count) assets")
    }
}
```

the func `onDoneSelection` returns an array of assets that contain the info of where the asset is located : on the device, iTunes library or iCloud.

if you just need to display the images you can use the this code in a collection view or something similar just implement this peace of code

```
var representedAssetIdentifier: String!

func getImageFrom(asset: Phasset) {
     representedAssetIdentifier = asset?.localIdentifier
    let imageManager = PHCachingImageManager()

    imageManager.requestImage(for: asset!, targetSize: self.frame.size, contentMode: .default, options: nil) { (image, _) in

        if(self.representedAssetIdentifier == self.asset?.localIdentifier &&
             image != nil) {
             self.imageView.image = image
        }
    }
}
```

this will show just the thumbnail, but is awesome because is also showing the thumbnail for live photos, and videos

#### Images and Videos as Data

The lib is intended to be used for sending images or videos over the network, and not to do fancy image or video editing. But this doesn't mea you can't. You can do just about anything since it returns an array of assets, but is you job to implement what you need.

in order to get the data from the asset ImageVideoPicker has one method that will return an completition handler with the data.

```
ImageVideoPicker.getDataFrom(asset: asset) { (data) in
    if data == nil {
        print(data as Any, asset.mediaType, asset.localIdentifier)
    } else {
        print(data!.count as Any, asset.mediaType, asset.localIdentifier)
    }
}
```

that will be all
have fun

Comment: is open source, the framework is made by one main file. just implement into your app

Comment: @StackUnderflow I don't believe your comment has a place on StackOverflow. It's an opinion, factually wrong, and unnecessarily negative. OP is providing a useful piece of software to the open-source community and cocoapods is a very well-established package manager.

Comment: @yspreen i am the op :D

Comment: That's true. There was another comment here before, but it was deleted for community guideline violations I guess. All good!

Answer (score 0):

```
func startMediaBrowserFromViewController(viewController: UIViewController!, usingDelegate delegate : protocol<UINavigationControllerDelegate, UIImagePickerControllerDelegate>!) -> Bool {
  if UIImagePickerController.isSourceTypeAvailable(.SavedPhotosAlbum) == false {
    return false
  }
  let mediaUI = UIImagePickerController()
  mediaUI.sourceType = .SavedPhotosAlbum
  mediaUI.mediaTypes = [kUTTypeMovie as String]
  mediaUI.allowsEditing = true
  mediaUI.delegate = delegate
  presentViewController(mediaUI, animated: true, completion: nil)
  return true
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Updated for the current version of Swift:

```
// Check if the asset is of video media type.
guard (asset.mediaType == PHAssetMediaType.video)   else {
    print("Not a valid video media type")
    return
}

// Obtain the URL of the video.
PHCachingImageManager().requestAVAsset(forVideo: asset, options: nil, resultHandler: {(asset: AVAsset?, audioMix: AVAudioMix?, info: [AnyHashable : Any]?) in
    let asset = asset as! AVURLAsset
    print("asset.url: ", asset.url) // Here is video URL
    // Play the video.
    DispatchQueue.main.async(execute: {

        let player = AVPlayer(url: asset.url)
        let playerViewController = AVPlayerViewController()
        playerViewController.player = player
        self.present(playerViewController, animated: true) {
            playerViewController.player!.play()
        }
    })
})
```

Answer (score -1):

```
if UIImagePickerController.isSourceTypeAvailable(UIImagePickerControllerSourceType.PhotoLibrary) {
  println("Camera Available")
  var imagePicker = UIImagePickerController()
  imagePicker.delegate = self
  imagePicker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceType.PhotoLibrary
  imagePicker.allowsEditing = false
  self.presentViewController(imagePicker, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

Delegate method

```
func imagePickerController(picker: UIImagePickerController!, didFinishPickingImage image: UIImage!, editingInfo: NSDictionary!) {
  self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
  imageView.image = image
}
```

Comment: I already tried all these. Application is closing automatically after compressing video. Unable to find the issue.

Comment: is that App crashing ?