# open only videos from library

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode

I have two button to get images and to get videos from device.
For Image button i code like this

```
- (IBAction)btn_image:(id)sender{
UIImagePickerController *img=[[UIImagePickerController alloc]init];
img.delegate=self;
img.sourceType=UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary;

[self presentViewController:img animated:YES completion:nil];}

- (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info{
[self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
UIImage *img=info[UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage];
imgview.image=img;}
```

In this code shows only images..
but when i press btn_video then how can i see only videos from device and no images.
I don't want to record video from camera.
 please give me code..

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to select any Video or Movie file from UIImagePickerController](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10480170/how-to-select-any-video-or-movie-file-from-uiimagepickercontroller)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

put this line in your button code :

```
UIImagePickerController *img = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
        img.delegate = self;
        img.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary;
        img.mediaTypes = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:(NSString *)kUTTypeMovie, nil];
        [self presentModalViewController:imagePicker animated:YES];
```

and Add `Frameworks` `MobileCoreService`

get Video from `didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo` :

```
- (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info
{
 NSString *mediaType = [info objectForKey: UIImagePickerControllerMediaType];

        // Handle a movie capture
        if (CFStringCompare ((CFStringRef) mediaType, kUTTypeMovie, 0) == kCFCompareEqualTo)
        {
            [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:Nil];
            NSString *moviePath = [[info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerMediaURL] path];

            if (UIVideoAtPathIsCompatibleWithSavedPhotosAlbum(moviePath))
            {
                UISaveVideoAtPathToSavedPhotosAlbum(moviePath, self,@selector(video:didFinishSavingWithError:contextInfo:), nil);
            }
        }
}
```

video delegate method :

```
-(void)video:(NSString*)videoPath didFinishSavingWithError:(NSError*)error contextInfo:(void*)contextInfo
{
    if (error)
    {
        UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Error" message:@"Video Saving Failed"
                                                       delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil];
        [alert show];
    }
    else
    {
        UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Video Saved" message:@"Saved To Photo Album"
                                                       delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil];
        [alert show];
    }
}
```

Comment: I always find the best way to see if a question is a duplicate is to search for any code you add to your answers as you constantly use other people's answer without attribution...

Comment: its my own answer not copyed anywhere @Droppy

Comment: I implement that code but my app terminated.  `Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'No available types for source 0'`

Comment: yeah that code worked.. but when i click on video it play it.but i dont want to play the video i want to show it in view as like image...

Comment: when i choose  a video a view appear and there is a choose button on pressing this it compressing what happened that @Jay Bhalani

Comment: No i dont Want to play video i want upload that video on server

Comment: you can get video from this method , See my edited answer @bhavinramani

Comment: got error on `@selector(video:didFinishSavingWithError:contextInfo:)`

Comment: on this code `NSString *moviePath = [[info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerMediaURL] path];` the error is `/Users/mymac/Desktop/single image/single image/ViewController.m:43:19: Incompatible pointer types initializing 'NSString *__strong' with an expression of type 'CGPathRef' (aka 'const struct CGPath *')`

Comment: I want to saw that selected video to my view.not to save anywhere