# ios - Determine if image picker media type is video or photo

Tags: ios, swift, image, video, uiimagepickercontroller

I have UIImagePickerController which is choosing photo or video from gallery, after selecting item, I want to determine which one is chosen, photo or video

```
 func imagePickerController(picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [String : AnyObject]) {
    let mediaType = info[UIImagePickerControllerMediaType]

 }
```

I've found this: [How to select any Video or Movie file from UIImagePickerController](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10480170/how-to-select-any-video-or-movie-file-from-uiimagepickercontroller)

but could not translate to Swift:

```
 if (CFStringCompare ((__bridge CFStringRef) mediaType, kUTTypeMovie, 0) == kCFCompareEqualTo) {

 }
```

thank you in advance

Answer (score 12):

Use this

```
if let mediaType = info[UIImagePickerControllerMediaType] as? String {

    if mediaType  == "public.image" {
        print("Image Selected")
    }

    if mediaType == "public.movie" {
        print("Video Selected")
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

**Swift 4. Use this:**

```
guard info[UIImagePickerControllerMediaType] != nil else { return }
let mediaType = info[UIImagePickerControllerMediaType] as! CFString

switch mediaType {
case kUTTypeImage:

    break
case kUTTypeMovie:

    break
case kUTTypeLivePhoto:

    break
default:
    break
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
if mediaType.isEqualToString(kUTTypeImage as String){

}
```

Worked :)

Answer (score 0):

**> Swift 4**
Override `didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo` like this:

```
public func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [UIImagePickerController.InfoKey : Any]) {
    guard let mediaType = info[UIImagePickerController.InfoKey.mediaType] as? String else {return}

    switch mediaType {
    case kUTTypeMovie:
        //handle movie here
    case kUTTypeImage:
        //handle image here
    }}
```