# Show image or video on same tableview cell?

Tags: ios, swift, image, uitableview, uiimagepickercontroller

I want to get either image or video from photolibrary and display on same tableview Cell.
I already get image or video from photo library using imagepickercontroller,  but don't know how to display on same cell(suppose user select photo then show photo on cell , if user select video , play video).

Note: I select photo from gallery, and don't want to save it.
Note: I don't want to use any 3rd party library.

Answer (score 0):

After selecting the content identify if it is an image or video. Refer this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35382970/ios-determine-if-image-picker-media-type-is-video-or-photo) .

In the Cell add both imageView and videoPlayer. And hide one of them after selecting.

Comment: Hi, yes mediaType can solve one issue, but main issue is 
how can I load a video or photo without array?( I mean without save it.)

Comment: You will have to store image or video in local array to show in Cell. Otherwise you wont be able to reload Tablecell

Comment: @Kudos I have take array as type of Any - is it okay?

Comment: Also when showing video in cell. Its better to use thumbnail of video.

Comment: Anyone please tell me how to play video after selecting from gallery?

Comment: @Amila 
I have take one array as 
var anArray : [Any] = [] to store image (get from gallery) and video (from gallery) then show on one cell.
it working almost fine when I select only images or only videos, but it app crash when I select first picture and then video.
error says **Could not cast value of type 'UIImage' (0x1dcaf3da8) to 'NSString' (0x1dcaa9f38).**
how can I fix it?