# Not able to pick video from iOS simulator 9.3 using imagepicker

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios-simulator, uiimagepickercontroller

I am using an `UIImagePickerController` to pick both *videos* and *images*. When using the simulator to pick a video the corresponding `delegate` isn't firing. It does however work as expected for images.

```
- (void)imagePickerController: (UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info
```

Comment: What you give for mediaTypes?

imagePicker.mediaTypes = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:(NSString *)kUTTypeMovie,      nil];

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10480170/how-to-select-any-video-or-movie-file-from-uiimagepickercontroller  Hope this link helps you.

Comment: It seems to be the Simulator problem. I completely reset the simulator and now it seems to be working fine. Simulator -> Reset Content & Settings.