# How to post a video selected from the library on an apple device to a view controller in xcode using swift

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, video, viewcontroller

I would like to choose a video from the library(which I have completed) NOW, I want to take that video and display it in a view controller. What do I do? I have looked everywhere and have found nothing.

```
  Here is my code for trying to get the file name of a selected video from the library, which I am trying to display in a webview. It does not work.
```

videoURL = info[UIImagePickerControllerReferenceURL] as! NSURL?

let fileURL = NSURL(fileURLWithPath: " (videoURL)")

videoView.loadHTMLString( " ", baseURL : nil)

Any help is much appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to play a local video with Swift?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25348877/how-to-play-a-local-video-with-swift)

Answer (score -1):

You'll need to implement the delegate methods.. Check this out:

[How to select any Video or Movie file from UIImagePickerController](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10480170/how-to-select-any-video-or-movie-file-from-uiimagepickercontroller)